# bash script didn't work in sequence by running in cron

Tags: bash, cron

I run a few scripts 1 by 1

cat 001.sh

```
sh /home/mysqldom/da-cron/f_mysqldom_nrd/5_change_nrd_tld.sh
sh /home/mysqldom/da-cron/f_mysqldom_nrd/5_proxy_removed.sh
sh /home/mysqldom/da-cron/f_mysqldom_nrd/6_sync_nrd.sh
```

The last script wont work... if I run manually it work very well...

the script is

cat 6_sync_nrd.sh

```
source /home/mysqldom/da-cron/var.sh
cd /home/mysqldom/da-cron/f_mysqldom_nrd/

mysql -u mysqldom_fnrd -p$mysqldom_fnrd_password -D mysqldom_fnrd -e "UPDATE \`$yesterday\` SET sync='$yesterday';"
mysql -u mysqldom_fnrd -p$mysqldom_fnrd_password -D mysqldom_fnrd -e "DELETE FROM \`$yesterday\` WHERE domain_name = 'domain_name';"

sed s/change_database/$yesterday/g update.conf > $yesterday.conf
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f $yesterday.conf  --path.data /var/lib/logstash108 



rm -rf nohup.out
```

The 6 has to be run after 5
any idea whats worn in it

Comment: Is  6_sync_nrd.sh  dependant on  5_proxy_removed.sh  being completed, and have you confirmed that it is not still running in background when  6_sync_nrd.sh  begins ?  Other than that, I can only imagine environment variable is missing.  suggest you capture output of  'env' and 'set' in separate files and run in both manual and script mode to compare differences in those provided values.  Maybe also check privileges of cron vs yourself for execution.

Comment: There is no indication of the format of $yesterday.  If it includes spaces, you need to wrap the variables outside of sed with double-quotes and the s/ part of sed needs to be wrapped in single-quotes.